# SelectMenu from JQuery UI not selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-selectmenu

On an older version of jquery (and related files), I had an issue where the menu that pops out of the selectmenu would appear in the top left corner no matter what. I updated all my files to the most recent, and now the first problem is fixed, but the default item doesn't appear in the box, and no selected item will appear either. The 'icons'option doesn't do anything at all either, but the width works as it should. There are no errors in the console either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Make a Reservation</title>
<link href="jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="form.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#letter" ).selectmenu({
        icons: { button: "ui-icon-circle-triangle-s" },
        width: 55,
        position: { my : "center", at: "center" }
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: +2
    });
}); // end ready
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        Unit 11 Demonstration
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="main">
            <h1>I'll figure out what to type here later</h1>
            <form>
              <div>
                <label class="label">Select a date:</label>
                <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">
              </div>
              <label class="label">Select a letter:</label>
                <select name="letter" id="letter">
                  <option selected="selected">A</option>
                  <option>B</option>
                  <option>C</option>
                  <option>D</option>
                  <option>F</option>
                </select>
            </form>
```

Nothing after this section of code is at all relevant. I have searched through all solutions I can find and have had no luck.

Comment: Note that all those `min` files are duplicates of the same file without `min` but are smaller file size. No need for both

Comment: I've discovered the width was my problem for the text appearing, because the icon is blank I had to add even more width. The icon still will not work however.